# How can I add value of textbox in table below it, while clicking a button?

Tags: jquery, button

I have a form, where I have textbox, then a button, and then a table.
Now, if I enter some value in textbox, and click the button, I want to add that value in the table below it.

How can I do it using JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: can you show the code you have tried ?

Comment: show the code that u have tried..

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Yes, he should have +1 your comment

Comment: @NullPoiиteя its the same timings.. just a millisecond ahead of me

Comment: I don't know how to get the value of textbox to table, so have simply created a table so far, but can not get the value..

Comment: `var someFieldValue= document.getElementsByName('someName')[0].value` and than write this value to html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this simple demo but keep in mind this will keep appending rows to your table

https://jsfiddle.net/0q5p1rwg/

```
   $("#submit").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $("#inputText").val();
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
});
```

Comment: any errors? did you check the syntax ? can you share your code ?
you can also use $('#table tr:last').after(); instead of append..

Comment: try again and add tbody selector

Comment: how would I do that? I don't know it..sorry

Comment: ' <body>
<form>
      <input type="text" id="inputText">
       <button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<table id="myTable">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $("#inputText").val();
    $('#myTable').append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');
 });
    </script>
  </body> '

Comment: Worked just fine